# SQLike - understanding the basics

Tags: javascript, json, sqlike

I'm trying to use the query engine 
[SQLike](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sqlike.html) and am struggling with the basic concept.

The JSON I'm using as my data source comes from my PHP code, like so:

```
var placesJSON=<? echo json_encode($arrPlaces) ?>;
```

Here's a sample JSON:

```
var placesJSON=[{"id":"100","name":"Martinique","type":"CTRY"},{"id":"101","name":"Mauritania","type":"CTRY"},{"id":"102","name":"Mauritius","type":"CTRY"},{"id":"103","name":"Mexico","type":"CTRY"},{"id":"799","name":"Northern Mexico","type":"SUBCTRY"},{"id":"800","name":"Southern Mexico","type":"SUBCTRY"},{"id":"951","name":"Central Mexico","type":"SUBCTRY"},{"id":"104","name":"Micronesia, Federated States","type":"CTRY"},{"id":"105","name":"Moldova","type":"CTRY"}];
```

I understand (via this [reference](http://www.thomasfrank.se/SQLike/)) that I first need to unpack my JSON like so:

```
var placesData = SQLike.q(
       {
       Unpack: placesJSON,
       Columns: ['id','name','type']
       }
    )
```

And the next step would be to query the results like so:

```
var selectedPlaces = SQLike.q(
               {
               Select: ['*'],
               From: placesData,
               OrderBy: ['name','|desc|']
               }
```

Lastly, to display the results in the browser I should use something like:

```
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=selectedPlaces[0].name
```

This doesn't work. The error I get is: selectedPlaces[0].name is undefined.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing out on something very simple. Any hints?

Comment: please post what `placesJSON` contains

Comment: thg435, I edited the question to include a sample JSON.

Comment: from what I can see, there's no need to "unpack" this Json, because it's already an array of objects.

Comment: Bingo, thg435! That was the very simple thing I was missing out on :-)

I don't see an option to vote your comment and mark my question as answered, but yours was indeed the answer.

Comment: answer posted. feel free to accept ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Unpack" converts an array of arrays, like `[["John", "Peterson", 38, 28000], ["Vicki", "Smith", 43, 89000]]` into an array of objects. Since your Json is already in this format, there's no need to unpack it.